# Why is DIV of HTML lightweight?

Tags: html

HTML Table is heavier than HTML DIV in terms of memory requirement and speed. I need to understand why DIV is lighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A div is a single element, not a collection of them.
- All else being equal, a div is `display: block` which is a much simpler layout algorithm to handle than the combination of `display: table`, `display: table-row` etc that apply to the elements that make up the table.

Comment: Maybe also that a div by default has no style and almost no behaviour.

Comment: What I meant with style and behaviour is everything but this bullet point. Rendering and Event-Listening is what I was after.

Comment: @kalsowerus — Rendering is just the act of converting the style into pixels. There are no event handlers bound on a table or a div by default.

Comment: That's what I meant, by default a div only rearranges its children when scaled, that's its only 'behaivour'. Maybe my bad choice of words.